# How to republish an ASP.NET Core 5 web application in IIS. Changes not taking effect

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I've published an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API to IIS (using VS 2019 webdeploy), and it is running fine. Now I've made some minor changes and republished.

The changes take affect on my local machine using IIS Express, but I do not see them when I publish to my IIS server. I can see that the exe and dlls are updated, but the webapi behaviour does change.

Something as simple as setting the swaggerdoc title doesn't take affect.

Is there something else I need to do to refresh the app?  I've tried recycling the app pool and doing an iisreset, but no luck.  I've read that IIS is merely acting as a reverse proxy to Kestrel which is actually hosting the api.  If so how do I recycle that?

As a test, I delete all the files in my web api directory. I browse to the web api and get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime Common
> solutions to this issue: The specified version of
> Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> Check the system event log for error messages
> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages Attach a
> debugger to the application process and inspect For more information
> visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526

I then re-publish the web api and browse to it, but it still has the old behavior. I'm really confused, because I know the published dll for my service is correct.

If I use ILSpy I can see the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfigurationSection appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");

    ApplicationSettings appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<ApplicationSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton(appSettingsSection.Get<ApplicationSettings>());


    services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddJsonOptions(delegate(JsonOptions o)
    {
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(delegate(SwaggerGenOptions c)
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "My Demo Service (" + appSettings.Environment + ")",
            Version = "v1"
        });
    });
}
```

When I browse to the swagger page of my API on my local dev box the title matches code, and the property naming is what I want. When I browse to it on the server, the title of the swagger page is the old value, and the property naming policy is camel case, so I'm pretty sure I'm publishing the new version of my web api, but it's not being executed when I make http requests to the api. Something must be cached somewhere.

Comment: How did you "publish"? via Pipeline or VS 2019? Have you tried manually deleting all files and then re-publish? That seems to work for my team...when this happens. We had to adjust our pipeline to wipe the directory first.

Comment: @ Published via VS 2019 using web deploy.  I took your advice, and deleted all the files, the re-published.  Before re-publishing, I browsed to the api swagger page and got an error that the app didn't exist, so I know I'm dealing with the correct app directory.  After I re-published  I got the same problem.  I used ILSpy on my published dll to prove that it was in fact publishing the new version of my api.  See edits on my post.

Comment: is it possible you are experiencing browser caching?

Comment: I think I know what is happening.  I am publishing my webapi project to http://myserver/dir1/dir2/mywebapi.  When I first published,  I mistakenly published to the root of the default web site.  Then I fixed that and published to the proper path.   I think it was finding the old dll in the root.  When I delete the files in the root of default we site, it works.  I didn't realize that it would look  to the web site root first